# Estimators in the case of refression with normally distributed errors

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, machine-learning, least-squares

How can it be shown that the *Maximum Likelihood Estimator* and the *Least Squares Estimator* are equvalent in the case regression with normally distributed errors? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that this is only true if all the erros have the same normal distribution! Now for a hint: Just write down the likelihood, which you want to maximize. Then take the log, the maximizer is still the same and the resulting expression should be familiar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have some points $y_{1},y_{2},\dots,y_{n}$
  and we have the model $$y_{i}=x_{i}^{T}\beta+\xi_{i}$$
 where the $\xi_{i}$
  are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$
  noise terms, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  and $x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$. This can be rewritten as $y=X^{T}\beta+\xi$
 where the columns of $X$
  are $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ and $\xi$ is a vector of noise.
 Now, the probability of $y$
  given $\beta$
  is $$P(y:\beta)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i:\beta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_{i}-x_{i}^{T}\beta)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sigma^{n}}\exp\left(-\frac{\|y-X^{T}\beta\|_{2}^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right).$$ Since the exponent on the right hand side is $\|y-X^{T}\beta\|_{2}^{2}$ which is the sum of squares error, we see that the probability is maximized when this quantity is minimized. Consequently, $\beta$ is the same for both the $MLE$ and linear regression.